# using projections to fetch certain columns through criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I would like to implement the following SQL query with Hibernate Criteria:

```
select abc_id, count(*) from boa_rep_deed where sync_system = ? And hook_id = ? group by abc_id order by abc_id
```

what I have tried is this ...

```
List<teedObject> hytlow = null;
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(teedObject.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("abcID ", abcID));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("syncSystem", syncSystem));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("hookId", hookId));

        hytlow = criteria.list();
```

Now my question is I have the corresponding pojo for this also as shown below..

```
class teedObject
{

    private long abcID ;
    private String syncSystem ;
    private String hookId;

    //and consisits other properties and setters and getters

}
```

Now I want my criteria to fetch only certain columns in order to make the object lighterso for that I have to use the projections in the criteria , can you please advise how to use projections in my case in order to fetch only certain coulmns

Answer (score 0):

Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(teedObject.class);

cr.add(Restrictions.eq("syncSystem", syncSystem));

cr.add(Restrictions.eq("hookId", hookId));

cr.addOrder(Order.asc("abcID"));

cr.add(Projections.groupProperty("abcID")));

cr.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());

hytlow = cr.list();